# Build and push docker-compose image into container registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I would to create a docker image using `docker-compose` and push it into the `gitlab container registry`. The `docker-compose` file has some `build.args` so during compile compile I pass the env file using the `--env-file` flag.
The `Dockerfile` image is a two step: `base` and `production` and this is the contents:

```
FROM node:17.0-alpine AS base

ARG GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .npmrc ./
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . .

FROM base AS production

RUN npm run build
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
  aaa-bbb:
    container_name: ccc
    environment:
      - GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN=${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
      args:
        GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}
        PORT: ${PORT}
    image: aaa-bbb/ccc:${TAG_VERSION}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:${PORT}
    command: yarn start:dev
```

and this one is the `docker-compose.prod.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
  aaa-bbb:
    container_name: ccc
    environment:
      - GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN=${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: production
      args:
        GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}
        PORT: ${PORT}
    image: aaa-bbb/ccc:${TAG_VERSION}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:${PORT}
    command: yarn start:prd
```

To build the image I use this command: `docker-compose --env-file ./config/.production.env -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml build --no-cache`

This is the gitlab pipeline step to build and store into the container regristry the docker image:

```
create_image:
  image: docker
  stage: create-image
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - TAG_VERSION=$(awk -F= '$1 == "TAG_VERSION" { print $2 }' ./config/.production.env)
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - docker image prune -f
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - echo " Image creation started..."
    - docker-compose --env-file ./config/.production.env -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml build --no-cache
    - docker-compose --env-file ./config/.production.env push aaa-bbb/ccc:${TAG_VERSION}
    - echo " Image created successfully!"
```

This is the output of the pipeline:

```
Removing intermediate container 1187fec9a21e
 ---> b0c14918a07b
[Warning] One or more build-args [PORT] were not consumed
Successfully built b0c14918a07b
Successfully tagged aaa-bbb/ccc:1.0.0
$ docker-compose --env-file ./config/.production.env push aaa-bbb/ccc:${TAG_VERSION}
No such service: aaa-bbb/ccc:1.0.0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

As you can see, there is this warning: `[Warning] One or more build-args [PORT] were not consumed` that during my test in local it doesn't appear and second I have a service tagged as `aaa-bbb/ccc:1.0.0` but I can't push it because there isn't the service.

How can I fix this problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first issue is that in your `docker-compose.yml` you defined a build arg named PORT, but that is not present in your `Dockerfile`. Hence docker warns about it being defined but not used.

You can fix that by adding

```
ARG PORT
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

to the end of the `Dockerfile`. If you want to set a default value (for example HTTP port `80`) for as the port you can use this form: `ARG PORT=80`.

If you need any more information about `Dockerfile`s, you can read more about it in its reference documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

But that does not lead to the error. When pushing with `docker-compose` you use the service name instead of the image. So in your case the correct command would be

```
docker-compose --env-file ./config/.production.env push aaa-bbb
```

Also, you need to add the full URL for the image name in `docker-compose.yml`. I.e.:

```
services: 
  aaa-bbb:
    [redacted]
    image: your.gitlab.instance/perhapssomegroup/aaa-bbb/ccc:${TAG_VERSION}
    [redacted]
```

You can read more about `docker-compose` at https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/ and about its yml file at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

I suggest to have all the documentation links I posted on speed-dial (also called bookmark) as you might need them a lot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answare but, despite having done the login to the `container register` when the `docker-compose push` is executed it try to `push` on `docker.io` instead of gitlab container registry

Comment: right. You need to set the image: key with a full URL pointing to your own registry. I added this to the answer.

Comment: Note that `PORT` is syntactically incorrect. Do you mean `EXPOSE`?

Comment: You are right @th3g3ntl3man . Thanks for pointing it out. I fixed the answer accordingly.